# AS3: Remove Lines from a text file in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, text-files, filestream

I need to delete the last 3 lines of a text file and or rewrite the last three lines using ActionScript 3.0

I understand how to append a file but I am lost on how to count lines using filestream.

Comment: So, you want to know how to count lines using file stream or you want to know how to manipulate a String object to remove the last 3 lines and append new lines? Also, what have you tried? Can you show us your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try that:

```
private function trimTextFile(txtFile:File, trimNum:uint):Boolean{
    if(txtFile.exists){
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(txtFile, FileMode.READ);
        var tmp:Array = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable).split("\n");
        stream.close();
                
        stream.open(txtFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        for(var i:int = 0; i < tmp.length - trimNum; i++){
            stream.writeUTFBytes(tmp[i] +"\n");
        }
        stream.close();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
            
}
```

And call it like this

`this.trimTextFile(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt"), 3);`

Comment: This worked perfect, I have never used split before, but after looking it up it makes sense and seems simple enough, Thank You!

Comment: You´re welcome :) 

Could you accept the answer, so that others with the same problem might find it easier :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); //Creating a loader object
var myArray : Array;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded); //On complete event handler

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
   var myArray:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
   //once you have all the lines as elements of the array you can change them
   myArray[myArray.length -1] = "ABC";
   myArray[myArray.length -2] = "DEF";
   myArray[myArray.length -3] = "GHI";
}

loader.load(new URLRequest("myFile.txt"));

//Then write out the contents of the array,

var f:File=new File("path\to\file.txt");
var handle:FileStream=new FileStream();
handle.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
handle.writeUTFBytes(myArray);
handle.close();
```